# Openshift Webhook Authenticator for External cluster Authentication (webhookTokenAuthenticator)

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Im trying to setup webhook authenticator on Openshift.

I was able to setup everything correctly on Kubernetes cluster -
using `--authentication-token-webhook-config-file=/etc/kubernetes/manifests/customconfigs/auth-config.yml.` config I was able to setup external authentication endpoint. When I tried to login to cluster using

`curl -k https://CLUSTER_ENDPOINT:6443/api --header "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>"` I received a POST request in external authention service - working properly.

Now Im trying same on Openshift cluster, Im relatively new to OCP, testing on crc local openshift cluster.

The problem Im facing is Any change I make to any config is getting overridden by another operators/controllers.

Any input towards this would be helpful.  How do i set custom configuration.

- why are my changes getting overridden,(probably observers are making changes) how do i get around this.
- is there a master config that i need to set wrt authentication. Is this (webhook authenticator) achievable in Openshift?

Thanks